# Entity Framework. Save big object with child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I select from the database a list of objects of approximately this structure:

```
public static List<ProjectHeader> GetProjectHeadersWithEntries(int ProjectId)
    {
        using (var db = new ProjectContext(GlobalVariables.DBConnection))
        {
            var headers = db.ProjectHeaders.Where(x => x.ProjectId == ProjectId)
                .Include(x => x.ProjectRun)
                .Include(x => x.ProjectDeductionEntries)
                .Include("ProjectDeductionEntries.EmployeeDeduction")
                .Include("ProjectDeductionEntries.ProjectEntryType")
                .Include(x => x.ProjectEarningEntries)
                .Include("ProjectEarningEntries.ProjectEntryType")
                .Include("ProjectEarningEntries.Department")
                .Include(x => x.ProjectTaxEntries)
                .Include("ProjectTaxEntries.ProjectEntryType")
                .Include(x => x.Employee);
            return headers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Then from this list I take a certain object and make calculations there, for example:

-ProjectHeader CurrentHeader = _ProjectHeaders.FirstOrDefault();

-CurrentHeader.ProjectTaxEntries – all new objects are assigned, because the old ones need to be deleted and new ones must be written.

-CurrentHeader.ProjectDeductionEntries – the existing objects are changed.

-CurrentHeader.ProjectEarningEntries – the existing objects are changed.

How can I write CurrentHeader entirely into the database, and only those changes that I want, that there would not be overwrite CurrentHeader.ProjectRun, CurrentHeader.ProjectDeductionEntries.ProjectEntryType,  CurrentHeader.ProjectTaxEntries.ProjectEntryType …

Here is my recording function with my comments. I wanted to do this to create a completely new object:

```
public static ProjectHeader SaveProjectHeaderWithEntries(ProjectHeader header)
{
using (var db = new ProjectContext(GlobalVariables.DBConnection))
{
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

var oldTaxes = db.ProjectTaxEntries.Where(x => x.ProjectHeaderId == header.ProjectHeaderId);

db.ProjectTaxEntries.RemoveRange(oldTaxes);

db.SaveChanges();

foreach (var item in header.ProjectTaxEntries)
            {
                //item.ProjectEntryType = null;
                //item.ProjectRun = null;
                //db.ProjectTaxEntries.AddOrUpdate(item);`

                if (item.ProjectEntryType != null)
                    db.Entry(item.ProjectEntryType).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.ProjectRun != null)
                    db.Entry(item.ProjectRun).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

                if (item.ProjectTaxEntryId == 0)
                {
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
            //header.ProjectTaxEntries = null;
            //db.SaveChanges();

            //db.Entry(header.ProjectRun).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            //db.Entry(header.Company).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            //db.Entry(header.Employee).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

            foreach (var item in header.ProjectDeductionEntries)
            {
                //db.ProjectDeductionEntries.AddOrUpdate(item);
                //db.ProjectDeductionEntries.Attach(item);
                if (item.EmployeeDeduction != null)
                    db.Entry(item.EmployeeDeduction).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.ProjectEntryType != null)
                    db.Entry(item.ProjectEntryType).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.ProjectRun != null)
                    db.Entry(item.ProjectRun).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

                if (item.ProjectDeductionEntryId == 0)
                {
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in header.ProjectEarningEntries)
            { 
                //db.ProjectEarningEntries.AddOrUpdate(item);
                //db.ProjectEarningEntries.Attach(item);
                if (item.ProjectEntryType != null)
                    db.Entry(item.ProjectEntryType).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.Employee != null)
                    db.Entry(item.Employee).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.ProjectRun != null)
                    db.Entry(item.ProjectRun).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.CompanyLocation != null)
                    db.Entry(item.CompanyLocation).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.Department != null)
                    db.Entry(item.Department).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.JobCode != null)
                    db.Entry(item.JobCode).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                if (item.ProjectEarningEntryId == 0)
                {
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            if (header.Company != null)
                db.Entry(header.Company).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            if (header.Employee != null)
                db.Entry(header.Employee).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            if (header.ProjectRun != null)
                db.Entry(header.ProjectRun).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            if (header.ProjectHeaderId != 0)
            {
                db.Entry(header).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(header).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;

            return GetProjectHeaderWithEntries(header.ProjectHeaderId);
        }
    }
```

In this version, I get an error on the line *db.Entry (item.EmployeeDeduction) .State = EntityState.Unchanged;*:

Attaching an entity of type 'Project.Business.Entities.ProjectEntryType' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

If I change **EntityState.Unchanged** on **EntityState.Detached** I receive in *db.SaveChanges ();* error: 
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ProjectEntryType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProjectEntryType'. The duplicate key value is (200).
The statement has been terminated.

EF wants to create a new entry in the *ProjectEntryType* table, although I've placed *EntityState.Detached* everywhere.
Partially helped to make a record in the beginning:

```
foreach (var item in header.ProjectTaxEntries)
{
     item.ProjectEntryType = null;
     item.ProjectRun = null;
     db.ProjectTaxEntries.AddOrUpdate(item);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

But then in the list of objects **_ProjectHeaders** that is in the view are lost **ProjectEntryType** and **ProjectRun**. In ProjectHeaders *ProjectDeductionEntries.ProjectEntryType*, *ProjectEarningEntries.ProjectEntryType* and 
*ProjectTaxEntries.ProjectEntryType* == *null*.

How can I record with EF only those objects that I specify as Modified?